# Fantasy novel in which a wizard's bones are found in a chest and he is reanimated

Tags: story-identification, novel, wizards

Does anyone know this book? I have a strong memory of reading a story in middle school.

What I remember most is a scene where the main character discovers a chest with bones in it. When opened, the bones reanimate and become a wizard who helps the main character. I remember him being funny, I think? I remember something about a castle and some kind of mission towards it.

That's about it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: A reanimated wizard is a pretty heavy trope in fantasy - usually in a negative sense (i.e. evil wizard) rather than positive.  Lots of books this sort of thing happens in

Answer (score 2):

The bones belong to a warrior, not a wizard, but it might be [Crewel Lye](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/a/piers-anthony/crewel-lye.htm) from the Xanth series by Piers Anthony. The castle is Castle Roogna, where the Good Magician Humphrey lives. He will answer peoples questions, but they have to do a task for him in exchange.

Comment: Hmm, not that I want to admit to having read too much Xanth, but Castle Roogna was the residence of the kings of Xanth. I believe the one Humphrey lived in was just called the Good Magician's Castle.